# Hexadecimal folders showing in the App folder on Macbook Pro, Big Sur

Tags: itunes, finder, folders

On my Macbook Pro running BigSur, in the App folder, I see other subfolders with hexadecimal names `00` through `ff`.  If I delete these, they eventually reappear.   Some of the folders contain a file with the name such as `3e04febc0508c9c31b80dce7066e19cb3af182ac.file`
which seems to contain information about an audio file. I suspect it's something related to iTunes but can't find any settings that address this. Problem also was present before I did the BigSur upgrade.

What process is creating them and how do I permanently get rid of them? Or, Are these folders normally hidden and some setting was changed to make them visible?

I've searched extensively but haven't found anything.

Comment: Likely a rogue/out of control process. You could try starting in safe mode, if it stops then there is a non-apple process that is doing it. Also create another user and see if it happens there. Those are two ways to narrow down the possibilities. Let us know the results.

Comment: If you suspect it's itunes, what is the output of `ps aux | grep itunes` ? If there is any pid, then please try killing it and see if it still continues to create those files. If it does then we can say that, it was not itunes and something else.